# display the date in the current format language that being used, TYPO3

Tags: typo3, lang

The website I'm working on has two languages (English and German) so I need to display the date in a format that correspond to the current language being used from the user
this line indicate the format but I need to check the current language, how to do that?

```
<f:format.date format="d-m-Y">{newsItem.datetime}</f:format.date>
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply use a label (locallang.xlf) for the date format for each language.

```
<f:format.date format="{f:translate(id: 'dateFormat')}">{thedate}</f:format.date>
```

Then define the label `dateFormat` for each language, like `%d.%M.%Y`. Use the format in the percent symbol syntax, so internally `strftime` will be used, which uses locale aware names then for months etc.

Comment: Ah, didn't read the question right. This answer is the correct one. :)

Comment: Thanks That worked, actually without defining the format for each language

Comment: @OdayBanihani You do not need to define the format for each language but you *can*. Typically for for dates "m/d/Y" for US format and "d.m.Y" for DE

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `strftime` notations in your date viewhelper, e.g. `<f:format.date format="%d %M %Y">`.
It works only if you set your locales correct in TypoScript and if you have the correct locales installed on your server.

PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php
Fluid: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Format/Date.html#format

Comment: Actually, in this case `%x` should be used to leave the whole date format to the locale.